# Typescript indexed string type in Dictionary which is a union type of keys in implementation

Tags: typescript

I try to write bulletproof interface for my mocking utility.

Initially I had an interface which every mock have to implement

```
export interface MockaronI<T> {
  states: { [state: string]: () => T };
}
```

states here is a set of factory functions with arbitrary names which every mock has.

the problem that at some point inside my utility I am doing that pseudo-code

```
keysof GenericType (which extends MockaronI) ['states']
```

And getting **string** type which is too broad for me (because IDE autocomplete not working). I want to narrow it down to **existing states in states object**.

So basically I want something like that. But that is not valid syntax.

```
export interface MockaronI<T> {
  states: { [state: infer P extends string]: () => T };
}
```

Is it even possible to have dictionary type which is based on existing key names in states of interface implementation?

Comment: Isn't property name always either string or number? Could you add some example code to see your desired output?

Comment: @zhuber Yes i want union type of strings. which is existing object fields in context of generic interface

Comment: "existing states in states object"... what states object?  Please post a [mcve] so that people can figure out if their answer will actually solve your problem. Right now all I can say is: if you want a type to keep track of keys without knowing them in advance, you'll need the type to be generic in those keys, like `interface MockaronI<K extends string, T> { states: Record<K, ()=>T> }` and then make everything that uses it generic in `K` as well.

Comment: @jcalz Yes I want exactly what you wrote but the only difference that I want infer K instead of repeating myself by providing it as a parameter, because the interface implemented by different object literals 100 times.
It must be keys of class which implements the interface.

Comment: If you provide the requested [mcve] then I can show how I'd use the more generic `MockaronI<K, T>` type in a way that minimizes the amount of manual specification for `K`.  Without an explicit use case example I'm not sure what to write.